# How to prove this inequality $\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2}{b+c}\ge\frac{3a+2b-c}{4}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0$,show that
$$\dfrac{a^2}{a+b}+\dfrac{b^2}{b+c}\ge\dfrac{3a+2b-c}{4}$$

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM: 
$$\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{4}\ge a$$
and 
$$\frac{b^2}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{4}\ge b.$$
So 
$$\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2}{b+c}\ge a+b-\frac{a+b}4-\frac{b+c}4=\frac{3a+2b-c}4.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(a+b+b+c)\left(\dfrac{a^2}{a+b}+\dfrac{b^2}{b+c}\right)&\ge (a+b)^2 \\
 &\ge (a+b)^2 - \left(\frac{a -c}{2}\right)^2 \\
 &\ge (a+b - \frac{a -c}{2})(a+b + \frac{a -c}{2}) \\
 &= \frac{2a+2b-a+c}{2}\cdot \frac{2a+2b+a-c}{2} \\ 
 &= (a+2b+c)(\frac{3a+2b-c}{4})
\end{align}$$

So

$$ \left(\dfrac{a^2}{a+b}+\dfrac{b^2}{b+c}\right)\ge \frac{3a+2b-c}{4}$$